# How to find second child of class and click on it using C#.Net Gecko

Tags: c#, dom, gecko

I'm trying to find a way to click second child of class in gecko using C#.Net.

I have this code:

```
geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("resetprice");
```

to get element by class name, now i'm trying to find a way to click on second button both button contains same class.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer by myself.

```
Gecko.DOM.GeckoLinkElement next = new Gecko.DOM.GeckoLinkElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("resetPrice").ElementAt(1).DomObject);
next.Click();
```

That was easy, Thanks for down voter.